# Export Django view to static HTML files using Django API (i.e. not wget or other scraper)

Tags: python, django, api, static-html

I have several Django views that I want to export as a static HTML site (to host on AWS S3). The site doesn't use any authentication or dynamic features, so serving in static format is ideal.

Using [Django StaticGenerator](https://github.com/timetric/django-staticgenerator) ([original source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358245/dump-django-site-to-static-html)) or `wget -m` seems like a fine solution, but they require I run my web server (even if it happens to just be `manage.py runserver`).

I would prefer to use the Django API to retrieve the view's HTML.  For example:

1. Initialize the `request` object with a non-logged-in user;
2. Pass this to my view function/method;
3. Do something with returned HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use django [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#overview-and-a-quick-example)

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> response = c.get('/')
>>> response.content
```